# Two phones evaluate SimpleDateFormat(...).parse(String) differently. Why?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android (this is my first app, please be gentle :D) and I'm having a problem with my two phones, which do not seem to evaluate the milliseconds in the same way. I have a Samsung S4 with Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop) and a S3Neo with 4.4.2 (KitKat).

The problem arises in my `CalcUtils.timeToMillis(String time)` function, which I'm calling as follows: `referenceTime = CalcUtils.timeToMillis("32.50");`. I.e., both phones get the same parameter "32.50" in the call.

My S3Neo returns `I/CalcUtils: time '0:32.50' is 32050 ms` (I need the output in milliseconds for a swimming calculation and the results on this phone do not match my charts), while my S4 returns `I/CalcUtils: time '0:32.500' is 32500 ms` (this is what I would expect)

Below, the full code of my CalcUtils class:

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;


public class CalcUtils {

    private static final String TAG = "CalcUtils";

    public static int timeToMillis(int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds) {
        int result = minutes * 60000 + seconds * 1000 + milliseconds;
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("time '%d:%d.%d' is %d ms", minutes, seconds, milliseconds, result));
        return result;
    }

    public static int timeToMillis(String time) {
        List<String> formatStrings = Arrays.asList("mm:ss.SS", "ss.SS");
        for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
            try {
                Date timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(time);
                Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(timeFormat);   // assigns calendar to given date
                int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int milliseconds = calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                return timeToMillis(minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Could not parse: %s with format %s", time, formatString));
            }
        }

        // no time was parsed!
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I assume the problem originates in how the different APIs evaluate the milliseconds. I couldn't find any evidence about it, though. Which leaves me with several questions:

1. how am I supposed to know when I should pay particular attention to a call, because it might be API-dependent?
2. how do I even search for this kind of details? I can't possibly test every phone but I'm writing the app for my father, which has an ever older phone than mine :)
3. how do I fix this function, so that it will return the same result on both platforms? I could pass the time to my function as "32.500", but I'm actually not interested in the 'millesimal-part'... and, anyway, this does not answer the questions above.

**EDIT**
I digged in a little bit more. The problem seems to happen in `Date timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(time);`. After that call (**with the same parameters!**), the S3Neo already has 32050 and the S4 has 32500. I need both of them to return 32500, but in particular I'd like to know **why** this is happening.

Comment: The answer given by the S3Neo is actually correct, the parameters passed into the function are 0, 32, 50, which when calculated using the formula you provided yields 32*1000+50, on the other hand, the S4 got the parameters as 0, 32, 500, which then yields 32*1000+500. So both are correct.
Note that you are assuming the time to be 32.50 which is the same as 32.5 or 32.500, but actually, they are different as the milliseconds are relevant here, 500 is different from 50!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it doesn't really help me. I'm using the output of that function (milliseconds) somewhere else for a calcuation, and I have a reference table to know what to expect (it's a swimming chart). The output from the S4 yields to the correct result in the chart. How come the phones get different parameters for the *same* call?

Comment: I've taken your point on the fact that "it is actually correct" and edited my question. Thank you. I still don't understand how the two outputs could differ, though.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but the problem seems to be from the fact that you are doing the formatting for the output wrong, it should be this way rather
`Log.i(TAG, String.format("time '%d:%02d.%03d' is %d ms", minutes, seconds, milliseconds, result));`. Better still you can output the seconds, and milliseconds separately, also sometimes the clocks give an inaccurate value for the milliseconds.

Comment: i'm calling the function with "32.50" as parameter on BOTH phones. S3Neo evaluates it as '32050ms', S4 as '32500'. there is a difference in how they understand the same call. How is this possible? The log is just a log, I don't care about it. But I need the amount of returned milliseconds to be the same from a phone to the other. By the way, I noticed that the problem occurs higher up, it's probably a DateFormat.parse() problem. I'll edit my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing "SS" to "SSS".

The milli seconds is always 3 digit.

Comment: Thank you but actually changing the DateFormat to SSS did not solve my problem. Passing the String as "32.500" did. But my questions 1 and 2 are still open: why do they not deliver the same result and how could I possibly have a hint of that behavior (apparently millisec is always read as a 3 digits number but not in the same way...). Also, using SS is a valid option (since there are no 'centi-seconds'), so way can I not use it ^^

Comment: 32050 result looked to me like it was only parsing the SS. The Calendar, SimpleDateFormat and Date is there in Android since API 1, it is not a API issue. Try parsing using this "mm:ss.SSS" format only without using multiple formats in a loop. So input times may have to change to 00:32.500

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted since yes, the program works fine when using SSS... but actually I already knew that (see my point 3). I still don't know why my phones work differentlym, though. If it's not an API problem, what could it be?